# How to edit a legend for WMS map in layout

Tags: qgis, wms, legend, layouts

I'm working on a project in QGIS and I'm trying to edit a legend for a WMS map in a layout (see pic below). From what I read the legends for WMS maps are provided as images and therefore they cannot be edited. Is there any kind of workaround for this?

[image]

Comment: You should be able to edit the configuration to change what shows in the legend.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible, that field is not editable.

Comment: You could always edit the image outside of QGIS, then add it to the layout as a picture.